# I need to call a javascript or jquery from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to refresh the page and also populate the second drop down according to the value selected in the first drop down.

1. In PHP I select the drop down value. It calls Javascript function reloadproject() and reloads the page with the current value.
2. Then I get the value of project id using $_GET.
3. After reloading I need to call the function getblock(val) using the project id I got using $_GET and populate the second drop down I have.

```js
function reloadproject(val) {
window.location = 'market?id=' + val;
}

function getblock(val) {
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "list_flat_view_dd.php",
 data: 'project_id=' + val,
 success: function(data) {
  $("#block-list").html(data);
 }
});
}

function getflat(val) {
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "list_flat_view_dd.php",
 data: 'block_id=' + val,
 success: function(data) {
  $("#flat-list").html(data);
 }
});
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
<select name="project" style="width: 100%;" id="project-list" class="form-control select2" 
onChange="reloadproject(this.value);">
<option value="all">Select</option>
<?php while ( $project=m ysqli_fetch_array ( $results_project ) ) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $project[" id "]; ?>"<?php if(isset($_GET[ 'id'])){if($project[ "id"]==$ filter_project_id){ ?>selected="selected"
 <?php }} ?>>
 <?php echo $project[ "name"]; ?>
</option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
<?php if(isset($_GET[ 'id'])){ ?>
<input type="hidden" name="filter_project_id" id="filter_project_id" value="<?php echo $filter_project_id; ?>">
<?php } ?>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
  <select name="block" style="width: 100%;" id="block-list" class="form-control select2" onChange="getflat(this.value);">
<option value="all">Select</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
  <select name="flat" style="width: 100%;" id="flat-list" class="form-control select2" onChange="">
<option value="all">Select</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: why you need to reload the page? you can fill the dropdown without reloading the page

Comment: I need to reload the pages to show the page accordingly to the selected value. plus I need to populate the second dropdown

Comment: I need to reload the pages to show the page accordingly to the selected value -> does this mean your page content also dependent upon selected value in first dropdown?

Comment: Why do you need to use JavaScript to populate the second dropdown? You have all the information you need to populate it on the server, so you could do the whole thing in server side code.

Comment: I totally have three dependent drop downs which should be shown to user to select the needed one

Comment: @Suyog : yes . If I select the drop down Item it reloads the page with the selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use 'document ready' to call your 'getblock' function?:

PHP runs first: print the code in your document, and after that, with jQuery $(document).ready() you know that the document is printed and you already have your hidden input with the GET['id'] value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="filter_project_id" id="filter_project_id" value="<?php echo $filter_project_id; ?>">
```

And your script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($('#filter_project_id').val().length) {
         getblock($('#filter_project_id').val());
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First the dropbox reloads the page and using $_GET to enable another input box having project-id and this calls the ajax and jquery function to populate the second drop box without reloading.

```js
        
      function reloadproject(val){
   window.location='market?id='+val;
      }
   $(function() {
     if ($('#filter_project_id').val().length) {
       var project_id = $("#filter_project_id").val();
       if (project_id) {
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "list_flat_view_dd.php",
           data: 'project_id=' + project_id,
           success: function(data) {
             $("#block-list").html(data);
           }
         });
       }
     }
   });
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <select name="project" style="width: 100%;" id="project-list" class="form-control select2" onChange="reloadproject(this.value);">
    <option value="all">Select</option>
    <?php while ( $project=m ysqli_fetch_array ( $results_project ) ) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $project[" id "]; ?>"<?php if(isset($_GET[ 'id'])){if($project[ "id"]==$ filter_project_id){ ?>selected="selected"
      <?php }} ?>>
      <?php echo $project[ "name"]; ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</div>
<?php if(isset($_GET[ 'id'])){ ?>
<input type="hidden" name="filter_project_id" id="filter_project_id" value="<?php echo $filter_project_id; ?>">
<?php } ?>
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <select name="block" style="width: 100%;" id="block-list" class="form-control select2" onChange="getflat(this.value);">
    <option value="all">Select</option>
  </select>
</div>
```